# NSTableView error: Row 1 should be in the valid visible section

Tags: macos, core-data

I have a standard NSTableView in Cell based content mode, it's dataSource is an array controller attached to my AppDelegate's managedObjectContext. In the delegate, this code  deletes objects on a background thread (the db can have 30k+ objects so it's good to have a responsive UI and a progress bar and a cancel option):

```
-(void)deleteObjects:(NSArray*)objs completionBlock:(void (^)(void))aBlock
{
        [self showCancelButton:YES];
        __block __typeof__(self) blockself = self;
        dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [(AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
            [objs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [mainContext deleteObject:obj];
                if ((idx % saveSpace == 0) && (idx > 0)) {
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSError *error;
                        [blockself.managedObjectContext save:&error];
                        theProgressOverlay.filesCount -= saveSpace; //
                    });
                }
                if (isCancelled) {
                    *stop = TRUE;
                }
            }];
            NSError *error;
            [mainContext save:&error];
            NSLog(@"delete error: %@",error);
            if (aBlock) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self showCancelButton:NO];
                    aBlock();
                });
            }
        });
}
```

this method is called by the code:

```
    NSFetchRequest *toDelFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity];
    [toDelFetch setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *toDelObjs = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:toDelFetch error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    if (!toDelObjs || toDelObjs.count < 1) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    [self deleteObjects:toDelObjs completionBlock:{NSLog(@"Finished");}];
```

It all seems to work fine: the UI's responsive and the cancel button always works but every so often I get the error:

```
2012-12-13 19:31:53.352 QS[1399:403] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.51/TableView.subproj/NSTableRowData.m:2484
2012-12-13 19:31:53.353 QS[1399:403] Row 1 should be in the valid visible section
2012-12-13 19:31:53.358 QS[1399:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b773f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88715d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b773d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8db1a71f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c6003 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:] + 164
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c5ef2 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorRowIndex:inDictionary:withRowAnimation:] + 184
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c5e38 -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:] + 38
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c557c -[NSTableRowData _unsafeUpdateVisibleRowEntries] + 448
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff917c5397 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 95
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9175d854 -[NSTableView viewWillDraw] + 156
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c1f08 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c1f08 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c2796 -[NSScrollView viewWillDraw] + 43
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c1f08 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c1f08 -[NSView viewWillDraw] + 666
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff916c0c4d -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] + 1358
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff916bf9b8 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1039
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff916bf375 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 648
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7338e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b733846 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 374
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b708af9 __CFRunLoopRun + 825
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b708486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb352bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb3c4bf ReceiveNextEventCommon + 181
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb3c3fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff91683779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff9168307d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff9167f9b9 -[NSApplication run] + 470
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff918fbeac NSApplicationMain + 867
    29  QuickSlide                          0x00000001000019c2 main + 34
    30  QuickSlide                          0x0000000100001994 start + 52
```

A search with our dear friend, Google, shows a number of blogs stating that `Row 1 should be in the valid visible section` is a bug when the NSTableView is has `-reloadData` called 'too early', i.e. during `-awakeFromNib`. But that's not the case for me - deletions definitely happen after the app's fully awake. I've also commented out the `showCancelButton:` to make sure it's not my custom progress bar and tried

```
[contentArrayController setAutomaticallyRearrangesObjects:NO];
```

Can anyone tell me if there's a cunning trick to avoid this assert? Or even if it's matters? The app seems to continue ok but one of the blogs I saw said it was storing up trouble for later but didn't elaborate. The table does seem to refresh itself more slowly after it's thrown up the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. After about a week, I haven't had the problem... S*d's Law means that it will probably all kick off again now I've answered my own question.

Anyway, I was using the delegate methods:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
```

The table seemed to be getting populated as I wanted via an NSArray which was cached with NSManagedObjects from my CD DB.

I was getting the error mostly when deleting objects (despite as I thought, updating the array cache with an NSFetchRequest).

So in a clutching at straws kind of way, I decided to sub-class the NSTextFieldCell in each table column and bind the NSTableColumns to an array controller in my main nib file. This went surprisingly well and has added benefits regarding tooltips when hovering over the table rows. Anyway, touching more wood than is right to say, it all appears to have calmed down now..... I'll update this answer if that changes any time.

UPDATE: it seems that NSTableView and/or multithreading doesn't sit well with the UI api. I found that on returning from background threads things like NSDrawers and sheets won't animate - they ignore their standard methods like -orderOut and -toggle. Using the above and an NSView with delayed animation (perform selector after delay) seems to have completely settled the app down.